# RegEx: When given an string that does not match to pattern how to define if exist larger string (containing smaller one) that does match?

Tags: regex

I need to write simple program that takes 2 parameters (RegEx pattern and string) and if string does not match answers whether exist larger string (containing smaller one) that can match pattern.

**Example1** 
Input: "^\w+\s+\w+$" and "hello" are not match, but program will return 'true' because there is string "hello word" that contains first one and matches to given pattern

**Example2** 
Input: "^(abc)*$" and "ca" not match, but program will return true because there is string ab**ca**bc (contains ca) that matches to pattern.

In short, program needs to answer if such string exist (true/false).

C# (C++, Java) and any help will be appreciated. At least some direction how to do it.

Comment: which language and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: First of all, please do not call what seem to be pure simple texts that you want to match upon “expressions” - in combination with the topic, where the patterns are the actual (regular) expressions, that is quite confusing. _“but program will return 'true' because there is expression "hello word" that contains first one and matches to given pattern”_ – where “is” that? Do you have a list of possible texts, and "hello word" would be one of them?

Comment: @jjj  I need C#, but C++, Java will also do.

Comment: @CBroe No, I don't have list of all possible texts. I only need to answer if it's possible. That is if such expression exist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the regex you are passing.

- In first one, remove the backslash `\` before `$`
- In second one, change `()` with `[]` `(abc)*` match abcabcabc and likewise but `[abc]*` will match a, b, c, ac, ab, aaa, bc, null

In Java (from OP's comment : Java is OK)

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class RegExTest{
  public static boolean check(String pat, String test){
    return test.matches(pat);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(check("^\\w+\\s+\\w+$","hello"));
    System.out.println(check("^[abc]*$","ca")); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Look, these 2 regex'es are only examples. I need to get any regex and any string and if string does not match I need to answer if this string can be "fixed" (that is replaced by larger on that contains previous that does match).

Comment: As I mentioned, the problem is with your Regular Expression. I suggest you to improve skills in regex.

Comment: What you are doing is changing regex PATTERN. I need to to answer if input STRING can be changed, not pattern. It's not he same

Comment: and after you remove backslash `\ before $` in first one _hello_ still does not match and can be _"fixed"_ by _hello world_